# Coffee Beans for Homebrewing

Tags: ingredients, stout, coffee

I'm planning to brew a Coffee Oatmeal Stout in a couple of weeks and was curious about what kind of coffee beans most people use in their homebrews. I was thinking about roasting some beans myself maybe.

Comment: This question is a bit too subjective, and could easily lend itself to turning into a big list of types of coffee.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use a double French roast.  Very dark, very mellow.  I use about 5 oz. of coarsely cracked beans in secondary for aroma, then add brewed coffee to taste at packaging time.